# TestNG not showing up as an option under Wizard in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar, testng

I created a simple project in Eclipse (not a maven project) using Java 8. Whenever I right click on my project -> new to get to the Select Wizard pop-up and type in "TestNG" under the Wizards search field, it does not show up.

I have installed the dependency jars (snakeyaml-1.21, guice-4.1.0, jcommander-1.72, testng-7.1.0) under the Referenced Libraries in my Java Build Path as well as the TestNG plugins (TestNG version 7.2.0.202005051752,   TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration (Optional) version 7.2.0.202005051752, and TestNG P2 Feature version  7.2.0.r202003151902).

Why is it still not showing up? I followed every solution to fix this issue and none of them have solved it.